# sortBy and interact work together in mutual cooperation?

Tags: haskell, io

here's a snip from my code:

```
io f = interact (unlines . f . lines)

io (sortBy compare (read :: String -> Int))
```

so I read the lines, get the numeric value, and sort by them. Care to guide me in the right path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `comparing` from the `Data.Ord` module instead of `compare`:

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

io f = interact (unlines . f . lines)
main = io (sortBy (comparing (read :: String -> Int)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't really understand your question, but this is how I got it:

The function `interact` feeds the input from `stdin` into your program and puts the result to `stdout`. Using `lines` and `unlines`, you get both the input and output split by lines, so you can actually operate on this layer. Your function `io` now does nothing else then putting the function `f` into this framework.

Next, `sortBy compare` is nothing else than `sort`. So you basically convert the lines to numbers and sort them this way. The result is a list of numbers. You may have noticed, that your program fails to typecheck at this point, as `unlines` expects a `[String]` and not a `[Int]` for the input. Change your function to `map show $ sort (read :: String -> Int)` to fix this. I would actually write `map show $ sort (asTypeOf 0 . read) instead, making it an`Integer`instead of an`Int` and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sorry for the ambiguity - What I'm trying to do is compare the line numerically, not lexicographically. Hope that helps your answer

Comment: @Sam P: In this case, just stick a `map show` in front of the last line. Your code already compares numerically, but it doesn't typechecks. Please notice, that your code is not a program at all. In a real Haskell program, put the code that should be executed into a function called `main`.

Comment: Yeah, there's actually a whole lot of code that I've snipped out so that I can gain an objective answer. it seems that     map show (io ( sort (asTypeOf 0 . read)))
does not work... There's still a type mismatch

Comment: @Sam P Write `io . map show . sort $ read :: String -> Int))` instead. The argument of `io` must be of the type `[String] -> [String]`, but your `(sortBy compare (read :: String -> Int))` has the type `[String] -> [Int]`. That's where the mismatch occurs.

Comment: still have an error, sorry!

Expected type: [a0] -> [String] -> [String]
Actual type: [a0] -> [b0]